# Birthday Problem variation

Tags: probability, birthday

I am trying to find the probability formula for a variation of the Birthday Problem.

Suppose that there were just two people, there were $n$ possible birthdays for both, and each person could have multiple birthdays.  Person $A$ would have $a$ birthdays, and person $B$ would gave $b$ birthdays.

Given $n$, $a$, and $b$, what would be the probability formula to determine if any of the birthdays matched?  Obviously if $a=n$ then the probability is $100%$.  If both $a$ and $b$ are $1$, then the probability is $(n-1)^2/n$ (I think).  But I was trying to find the general probability formula for this.  Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Your formula can´t be right. For $n\geq 3$ the probability is greater than 1.

Comment: Btw: Is your "I think" an indication of Charles Darwin ?http://www.amnh.org/exhibitions/past-exhibitions/darwin/the-idea-takes-shape/i-think

Answer (score 1):

Hint: There are $\binom{n}{a} \binom{n}{b}$ total possible combinations of birthdays for $A$ and $B$. The number of combinations in which $A$ and $B$ do not share a birthday is $\binom{n}{a+b} \cdot \frac{(a+b)!}{a!b!}$.

Comment: ...still trying...

Comment: Is it 1- ((n-a)!(n-b)!)/(n!n!(n-a-b)!)  ?

Comment: @mark I think you have an extra $n!$ but otherwise yes.

Comment: Yes, yes, you are right.  Thanks.  This is great.  i finally have this formula!!!

Answer (score 1):

Notice that if we treat the birthdays as the numbers $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, then we can assume without loss of generality that $A$'s birthdays are $\{1,\ldots,a\}$. The probability that all of $B$'s birthdays are in the remaining days (i.e. that there is no match) is 
$$\frac{\binom{n-a}{b}}{\binom{n}{b}},$$
which simplifies to 
$$\frac{(n-a)!(n-b)!}{n!(n-a-b)!}.$$
It's questionable how much simpler this is, but it's nice to see it written symmetrically in $a$ and $b$.

I know this is very similar to the other answer, but it's a different way to think about it, and it's too long for a comment.

Comment: Yes, this is great Eric.  Your explaintion and angryavain's really helped me to understand this problem.  Now I have to run some examples to see what the probabilities are for some sample vallues of n, a, and b.  Thanks to all of you for your help!